# How to allow CORS with AngularFire Functions when developing on localhost

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire in a Ionic/angular app.

I'm trying to call a function:

```
const getDiretions = this.functions.httpsCallable('getDirections');
    const result = await getDiretions({
      lat1: lastStop.coordinates.latitude,
      lng1: lastStop.coordinates.longitude,
      lat2: step.coordinates.latitude,
      lng2: step.coordinates.longitude,
    }).toPromise();
```

But I get this:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://europe-west6-xxxxxx-yyyyyy.cloudfunctions.net/getDirections' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

What is the correct approach to make this request succeed from localhost?

**EDIT**
Sorry, here is how I initialize the `this.functions`:

```
  constructor(private functions: AngularFireFunctions) {}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the backend definition:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();


export const getDirections = functions.region('europe-west6').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const lat1: number = +(request.query.lat1 ?? '0');
  const lng1: number = +(request.query.lng1 ?? '0');
  const lat2: number = +(request.query.lat2 ?? '0');
  const lng2: number = +(request.query.lng2 ?? '0');


  //Do something with lat/lng


  response.status(200);
  response.send(answer);
});
```

Comment: Can you show how, in your front end, you have initialized Cloud Functions through Firebase (i.e. how do you define `this.functions`) as well as how you have defined the location of the function in your index.js? I try to check if you have set the appropriate value at initialization. since it seems that you call a function running in a location other than the default `us-central1` location. Also note that you don't need to call `toPromise()`, [HttpsCallable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions.HttpsCallable) already returns a Promise.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added some details. Regarding the location, I just added `{ provide: REGION, useValue: 'europe-west6' },` to my app.module.ts. I've done nothing else to setup function with angular fire. VS Code is telling me that httpsCallable is returning an Observable.

Comment: Can you show how you define the Cloud Function in your `index.ts` or `index.js` file (i.e. in the backend)?

Comment: "VS Code is telling me that httpsCallable is returning an Observable." => angularfire may encapsulate it in an Observable. I cannot say more on this side, I'm not versed in angularfire... :-)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added to the question how the function is declared in the backend. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Ohh, I see, your Cloud Function is not a Callable one but an HTTP one! Your are mixing the two types. I’ll write an answer in some few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually mixing [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Your Cloud Function code corresponds to an HTTP one (`functions.region('europe-west6').https.onRequest(...)`) but the code in your front-end calls a Callable one (`this.functions.httpsCallable('getDirections');`).

You should adapt one or the other, most probably adapt your Cloud Function to be Callable one (to get the advantages of a Callable), along the following lines:

```
export const getDirections = functions.region('europe-west6').onCall((data, context) => {
  const lat1: number = +(data.lat1 ?? '0');
  const lng1: number = +(data.lng1 ?? '0');
  // ...

  //Do something with lat/lng

  return {
    answer: answer,
  };
});
```

Comment: Wow, never tought there could be such difference, I was convinced that since it was angular calling backend, the backend call was just an HTTP call. I read the link you described, but I'm not totally sure, it's only about deserializing automatically and having the auth available? Anyway, I changed my function to be a callable one, and it works like a charm !!! Thank you so much!

Comment: "it's only about deserializing automatically and having the auth available?" Yes, these are the main advantages, plus the fact that you don't need an extra library (or using fetch) to call the Cloud Function. At the end a Callable Cloud Function is an HTTP one but with a very specific [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).